# undefined method `+@' for nil:NilClass rails after moving to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I moved the database to mysql which is on VM. After moving database I started getting this error when I am trying to access or saving data to database but some models updation are working fine.

The model I am accessing has some arithmetic computations which I feel is the reason for this issue.

Error is

```
undefined method `+@' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried from rails console as well and I am getting same error with this command

Settings.all

I guess this is part of that method method

```
if params[:lat] and params[:lon] and params[:rad] and !params[:lat].empty? and
                    !params[:lon].empty? and !params[:rad].empty?

  lat = params[:lat].to_f
  lon = params[:lon].to_f
  rad = params[:rad].to_f
  ear = 6371.00

  min_lat = (lat) - (rad/ear)/180.0*Math::PI;
  max_lat = (lat) + (rad/ear)/180.0*Math::PI;

  min_lon = (lon) - (rad/ear/Math.cos(lon*Math::PI/180.0))/180.0*Math::PI;
  max_lon = (lon) + (rad/ear/Math.cos(lon*Math::PI/180.0))/180.0*Math::PI;

  @settings = @settings.includes(:settings_location)
    .where("settings_locations.latitude  > :min_lat AND " \
           "settings_locations.latitude  < :max_lat AND " \
           "settings_locations.longitude > :min_lon AND " \
           "settings_locations.longitude < :max_lon", {
               min_lat: min_lat,
               max_lat: max_lat,
               min_lon: min_lon,
               max_lon: max_lon});
```

stack trace

```
Started POST "/settings.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-24 13:52:53 +0200

NoMethodError - undefined method `+@' for nil:NilClass:
  app/models/settings.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `block in load_file'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:616:in `new_constants_in'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load_file'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
```

`setting.rb`:

```
class Settings < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :settings_location

def to_builder
  Jbuilder.new do |json|
    json.location settings_location.to_builder
  end
end  //this line is 54
```

Comment: Right now it's hard to tell which is the 54th line :) Right now you should find which variable (on that line) is `nil` and trace through the call stack where it was supposed to be set.

Comment: line 54 is end of line in settings.rb file and after tracing I reached to this method that I mentioned above...:(

Comment: What's your `settings.rb` content?

Comment: I do not think that there would be any issue and everything was working fine when I was using sqlite3 but anyways I have updated settings.rb content

Comment: *line 54 is end of line in settings.rb file...* I don't know what that means. Could you please indicate which line in the code you're showing is line 54?

Comment: updated as per above comment

Comment: Is it really `+@`, and not `+`? The only way I can reproduce the same message in irb is by trying to execute `nil.send(:'+@')`. Any odds you've code along the lines of `foo.send(bar)` that is running underneath in there, possibly in an `eval` statement?

Comment: @Denis Yes, really `+@`, which is the unary `+` operator. Try running this: `+nil`.

Comment: just a question the same code was workiing well when I was using local sqlite3 ...why is not working now as I have not chaned code..only db...yes it is +@ for sure on Model Settings and moslty other models are working fine

Comment: Good catch. So that would presumably indicate some occurrence of `+var` deeper within @user1618's code somewhere.

Comment: This does not look like the full stack trace to me. Rails hides several steps by default. If you open the page in your browser, and get the stack trace, and click full, do you get a more comprehensive stacktrace? (alternatively, if you don't want to do this on your server, you can add a gem to mail the error, or use a service like sentry or appsignal to track it for you)

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, there seem to be only a handful of cases where you can reproduce the same error message in IRB. The first is:

```
foo, bar = nil, nil
foo.send("+@", bar)            # undefined method `+@' for nil:NilClass
```

The second is:

```
foo = nil
+foo                           # undefined method `+@' for nil:NilClass
```

In an `eval` context, the latter might more look like:

```
foo, bar = nil, nil
eval("foo = +#{bar.inspect}")  # undefined method `+@' for nil:NilClass
```

My personal guess is that your problem is something along the lines of the latter. Not with `eval`, but rather with one of its plethora of Ruby variations such as `define_method`. The actual call is very likely somewhere in Rail's internals and related to some uninitialized variable — perhaps MySQL is returning null where SQLite was returning *something* due to a recent schema change that you didn't think about?

Personally, I'd try to narrow it down step by step:

1. Comment out:

```
json.location settings_location.to_builder
```

If the error is gone, then:

2.a) Replace it with:

```
builder = settings_location.to_builder
json.location builder
```

If the error message is still the same, then:

2.b) Try

```
Jbuilder.new
```

… without a block.

The point is, you want to narrow things down to the specific method that is causing the error, and then dive into that method's code to see what is nil and shouldn't be. (Perhaps the block is missing some kind of return value?)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it did not work and I am very sure I did not change any migrations file so I guess there is no chance of schema change, now I will try analysis each and everything...

Comment: I do not know, I have tried almost everything I could but the same result tried to debugged it too with various gems but could not resolve the issue...I commented full settings model but still the same issue... any other suggestions please

Comment: @user1618: did you manage to isolate what was triggering the error by commenting out code until it disappeared?

Comment: I commented out the full settings model one by one..but could not found the line where it get disappeared Whenever I run "Settings.all" from any where it ends up with same error ...I removed many defined relations as well...Is it from mariaDB that I am using with MySql? or any other suggestion...

Comment: To be frank, I don't think there's much more I or anyone else can do to help as things stand. Highlighting as I did how I'd proceed to debug this is the best I can do, i.e. comment things out until the error goes away, uncomment and then dive into the relevant function's code and comment out things in there too until the error goes away, and so forth, until you peel all of the layers and identify the lower level piece of code that is truly triggering the error. From there, you'll know what argument is the culprit, and you can trace it back to where it came from using `caller` to identify why.